# Derive explicit expression of squeezed vacuum state in the Fock basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics, squeezed-states

I'm learning quantum optics, and I'm starting to manage boson algebra.

In particular, as a pure exercise, I would like to express a squeezed vacuum state in the Fock basis, which, according to [Weedbrook et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3234) is given by:
$$|0,r\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cosh(r)}}\sum_n\frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{2^nn!}\tanh r^n|2n\rangle$$
Where $r$ is the parameter associated with the squeezing operator
$$S(\xi)=\exp\left\lbrace\frac{1}{2}\left(\xi {a^\dagger}^2-\xi^*a^2\right)\right\rbrace ; \xi=re^{i\theta}$$
This expression can easily be obtained using [disentangling equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/416105/squeezed-state-and-bogoliubov-transformation) and assuming $\xi$ to be real. However, I asked myself if the same expression could be obtained by using simple algebra (like BCH formula), indeed:
$$|0,\xi\rangle=S(\xi)|0\rangle$$
Using BCH formula $e^{A+B} = e^Ae^Be^{-\frac{1}{2}[A,B]}$, I found that:
$$S(\xi)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\xi {a^{\dagger}}^2\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\xi^* {a}^2\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{4}|\xi|^2(\hat{n}+1)\right)$$
Where the last term has been obtained from:
$$-\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{1}{2}\xi {a^{\dagger}}^2,-\frac{1}{2}\xi^* {a}^2\bigg] = -\frac{1}{4}|\xi|^2[{a^{\dagger}}^2,a^2]$$
by applying different times the identity $\hat{n}=a^{\dagger}a=aa^{\dagger}-1$. Indeed:
$$[{a^{\dagger}}^2,a^2]=a^\dagger a^\dagger aa -aa a^\dagger a^\dagger=a^\dagger aa^\dagger a-a^\dagger a-aaa^\dagger a^\dagger =a^\dagger aaa^\dagger -2a^\dagger a-aaa^\dagger a^\dagger \\=aa^\dagger aa^\dagger -aa^\dagger -2a^\dagger a-aaa^\dagger a^\dagger =-2(aa^\dagger +a^\dagger a)=-2(\hat{n} + 1)$$

If I now apply this decomposition of $S(\xi)$ to the ground state, thanks to the properties of the number and annihilation operator, I have that:
$$S(\xi)|0\rangle=\exp\left({-\frac{1}{4}|\xi|^2}\right)\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\xi {a^{\dagger}}^2\right)|0\rangle=\exp\left({-\frac{1}{4}|\xi|^2}\right) \sum_n\frac{\xi^n}{n!2^n}{a^{\dagger}}^{2n}|0\rangle\\=\exp\left({-\frac{1}{4}|\xi|^2}\right) \sum_n\frac{\xi^n}{n!2^n}\sqrt{(2n)!}|2n\rangle$$
The first equality follows from the expansion of the two exponentials in Taylor series, and noticing that $a^n$ produces the 0 vector when acting on $|0\rangle$.

This expression is different to the one given in the literature, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with this derivation. Can you help me?

Comment: presumably you mean $(2n)!$.  You essentially have a different parametrization of your squeezing transformation.  The first step in reconciling the expressions is to convert $\xi$ to $r$ or vice-versa.

Comment: Seem to me that you've used the disentangling incorrectly. Perhaps you can have a look at the answer in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/416105/squeezed-state-and-bogoliubov-transformation

Comment: Assuming your first equation is correct. Quick Hint : $S(\xi)|0\rangle=e_{}^{i\frac{\text{Arg}(\xi)}{2}a_{}^{\dagger}a_{}^{}}S(|\xi|)e_{}^{-i\frac{\text{Arg}(\xi)}{2}a_{}^{\dagger}a_{}^{}}|0\rangle=e_{}^{i\frac{\text{Arg}(\xi)}{2}a_{}^{\dagger}a_{}^{}}S(|\xi|)|0\rangle$.

Comment: ZeroTheHero Yes! I mean (2n)! Instead of (2n!). Reconciling $\xi$ with $r$ is not needed in my case as $\xi$ is a 'generalization' of $r$ as it comprises complex numbers.

fippiefanus I have not used the disentangling equation. I just mentioned it because it is normally used to derive the Fock state ''expansion'' of squeezed states

@Sunyam thank you for your hint. However, my question is different. In particular, why the "standard" expression for squeezed states involves an hyperbolic tangent and an hyperbolic cosine? I can't really see where they come from using my derivation.

Comment: You say "using the BCH formula" but I don't see a simple way to use BCH to get what you have. Can you spell out the details of how you get the RHS?

Comment: @mikestone I have added the details in the question.

Comment: Check the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_explicit_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) for the BCH formula, you are not using it correctly. Note that $[A,B]$ doesn't commute with $A$ or $B$, unlike the application of BCH to e.g. unitary displacement operators which you might have seen before.

Comment: @MarkMitchison You are right. I was applying the BCH formula without veryfing if $[A,B]$ commutes with $A$ and $B$ (lot of simple Boson algebra in the last few days). That was my fault. Thank you so much for the spot!

Answer (score 3):

I’m willing to bet your commutator $[\hat a^\dagger \hat a^\dagger,\hat a\hat a]$ is wrong.

This is [because](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/524443/36194) 
\begin{align}
\hat K_+=\frac{1}{2} \hat a^\dagger \hat a^\dagger \, ,\qquad 
\hat K_-=\frac{1}{2}\hat a\hat a\, ,\qquad 
\hat K_0=\frac{1}{4}(\hat a^\dagger \hat a +\hat a\hat a^\dagger) \tag{1}
\end{align}
close under commutation on the algebra $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ so that $[\hat K_+,\hat K_-]$ is a multiple of $\hat K_0$, which is not proportional to $\hat n+1$ but rather to $2\hat n+1$.

A useful reference for the realization (1) and for this type of stuff is the book by Perelomov:

> Perelomov A. *Generalized Coherent States and Their Applications*, Springer.

As a bonus the squeezing transformation is basically an $SU(1,1)$ transformation, with matrix elements given in explicit form in

> Ui H. Clebsch-Gordan formulas of the SU (1, 1) group. Progress of Theoretical Physics. 1970 Sep 1;44(3):689-702.